# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - when running z/OS application

Tags: java, c, compilation, websphere, zos

When I am trying to run one of my Java application (which is deployed in IBM Websphere App server), I am getting the below error,

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: PATH/file.so (EDC5253S An AMODE64
>   application is attempting to load an AMODE31 DLL load module.
>   (errno2=**some_address**)) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1344)

Did anyone face the same issue of AMODE64 ?

Or could someone provide info on how to compile code to AMODE64.

Any reference in this would also be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On z/OS, you can't have a mixed single-address application that has some parts compiled 31-bit and some parts compiled 64-bit, if you are using Language Environment. All modern high level languages -do- use Language Environment (e.g. C, C++, Java, COBOL, PL/I), and so this is what is causing your problem. 
Depending on the version of Java you are using, you can either switch to a 31-bit JVM or (preferably) recompile and relink your C DLLs as 64-bit.

Comment: yes..after debugging we came to know the same..we have recompiled the C DLLs in Z/OS as 64 bit and now the application is working properly..thanks :)

Comment: you might want to upvote mine or F Rowe's so people can see the answers helped?

Answer (score 0):

You asked for info on how to compile code in 64-bt mode, but typically, as the end-user, you would not be the one to do that, the provider of the native library/dll would do that because you need the source code.  You replaced the file name of the library in the error message above with PATH/file.so, so I can't provide you any guidance on who the provider of that library might be.  Using the name of the library, search for for the provider and then ask them for a version of the library compiled in 64-bit mode.
On the outside chance you own the code for the library, see [this IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ceeam00/dllsim.htm) for information on how to compile and bind code in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @FRowe..thanks for the info..I have the source code of the library..it is a simple c file which is compiled in mainframes..and the generated library is called from java..previously we had 31 bit z/OS and now we have upgraded to 64 bit..because of this we are getting the AMODE64 error..my doubt is, is there any way to still use the 31 bit library (say keeping some flags) or should I recompile it and create a new library ?

Comment: Since you have the source code, you should be able to follow the instructions in the aforementioned IBM KC topic to recompile in 64-bit mode.

Comment: I was also checking the same link..thanks for the help :)